# Access tf Vector3 values

Tags: navigation, odometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to get the z position value of my robot in gazebo. My Robot is using a skid steering plugin publishing on the "/player0/odom" topic and the
"/tf" topic with
"player0/frame" as it's frame id.

I do know how to get the x and y values by using the odom topic, but to get the z value it seems I have to use tf.
However, the tf data confuses me.

If I echo the /tf topic, I get:

transforms:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 8
    nsecs: 402000000
  frame_id: player0/frame
child_frame_id: root
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: -2.00000384203
    y: -0.000426774126042
    z: 0.400000377264
  rotation: 
    x: -4.57302626635e-07
    y: 9.54536038539e-08
    z: -0.00161574482528
    w: 0.999998694683
```

How can I get the z: 0.4...value and store it into a variable?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263151/access-tf-vector3-values/) by [JulianR](https://answers.ros.org/users/30632/julianr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use a TransformListener to get transform information. Please see the tf2 tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JulianR](https://answers.ros.org/users/30632/julianr/) on 2017-06-05**:
Thanks you, I did look at those tutorials, but I still had some questions.
What really helped me understand the /tf access was looking at the tf_echo.cpp source file.